# How does PHP 7 return type coercion work for null?

Tags: php, null, php-7, return-type, coercion

According to [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration) for return type declarations (emphasis mine):

> .... In the default weak mode, **returned values will be coerced to the correct type if they are not already of that type**.

This means that the method `returnInt()`

```
class A {
    public function returnInt(): int {
        return "6a";
    }
}
```

will return the int value 6 (as it should).

However returning `null` from the function above throws a TypeError, even though null can be easily coerced to the integer 0 with `(int) null`

> FATAL ERROR Uncaught TypeError: Return value of A::returnInt() must be of the type integer, null returned

How come this won't work for null values?

What logic is PHP using when attempting type coercion?

Comment: Probably because null is a special case. This is why you have nullable return type using `?`.

Comment: as php docs says about http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php `public function returnInt(): ?int` since 7.1, but yes null can't be cast in int

Comment: Good question, but generally you should keep to best practice and work with the actual types instead of relying on PHP doing correct conversion.

Comment: @Frankich "null can't be cast in int" since when? https://3v4l.org/V2f6D

Comment: ok it's not that it can't be, it can't smart cast a null into int..

Comment: @Daniel Then do that. Don't return null, don't return non-int values. Issue averted *shrug*

Comment: Maybe because `null` in PHP is not a real type, it's a value but more like a C++ `void`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected and by design. You can find the original RFC for this feature at http://wiki.php.net/rfc/return_types.

Specifically there is a section `Disallowing NULL on Return Types` which states:

> this type of situation is common in many languages including PHP. By design this RFC does not allow null to be returned in this situation for two reasons:
>
> 1. This aligns with current parameter type behavior. When parameters have a type declared, a value of null is not allowed.
> 2. Allowing null by default works against the purpose of type declarations. Type declarations make it easier to reason about the surrounding code. If null was allowed the programmer would always have to worry about the null case.

Now, I can't see in this rfc any talk of type conversion, whereas the official docs do, so chances are null isn't converted simply because the RFC was explicit in saying it wasn't to work. Personally I think leaving null as the odd one out is weird. It was potentially also being consider as linked with the nullable types rfc, which may have made a difference to how null was determined to work.

I can't say I personally agree with how it's worked out, but I'm not a core developer :).

Answer (score 4):

The [rule](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/return_types#disallowing_null_on_return_types) on not returning `null` when declaring a typed return values supercedes the rule about [coercing returned values](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration) to the declared type.

The most important bit is this:

> This aligns with current parameter type behavior. When parameters have a type declared, a value of null is not allowed

If your function or method expects a non-nullable int as a parameter, you can't pass a null value and expect it to be coerced, but you can pass a string or a boolean, for example.

E.g.

```php
function foo (int $bar) {
    echo "Received: ", $bar, "\n";
}

foo("1");
foo(false);
foo(null);
```

The first two will work, [but the last won't](https://3v4l.org/mVrIX).

The RFC chose to align with this expection for consistency sake.

Your choices are the obvious ones, either return a nullable int:

```php
function foo(): ?int {
   return null;
}
```

Or if that's not desirable, just coerce your return value before sending it back:

```php
function foo(): int {
   return (int) null;
}
```